# did not get API's response in the form of HttpResponse

Tags: node.js, angular, api, backend

I am using node as a backend and Angular as fronend. I am calling one API. when an error is there then my API's response is in the form of HttpErrorResponse. but when I get actual data(my API does not have an error) then I did not get the response in the form of HttpResponse. I get direct data. in the Object form. what should I have tp do for getting response in the HttpResponse form.

Comment: HttpClient documentation :) https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: can you show me where exactly your solution is?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: does code matter ? @KibéM.C

Comment: I want to see the Angular function and debug

Comment: https://jmp.sh/PMuH6Rv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.